# SQL Query for top 10 items from two relations

Tags: sql

I'm struggling to right a SQL command to get the top 10 names from the following (using standard SQL, cant use TOP) for the following 2 relations:

```
      Orders (customer_email, item_id, date)
      Items(id, name, store, price)
```

Any advice on how to do this? I think I would need to group them, but then what do I do to get the top 10 groupings based on count?

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
  from (select x.*, row_number() over(order by num_orders desc) as rn
          from (select i.name, count(*) as num_orders
                  from orders o
                  join items i
                    on o.item_id = i.id
                 group by i.name) x) x
 where rn <= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) count_per_item
  , i.id
  , i.name
FROM   
    Orders o 
JOIN   
    Items i 
ON  (o.item_id = i.id)
GROUP BY
    i.id
  , i.name 
ORDER BY
    count_per_item DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: The OP states that the question should be answered _using standard SQL, cant use TOP_ LIMIT is equivalent to TOP in this case and is as far as I know not part of the standard.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could *edit your answer* and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.